# How can you deploy a spring boot application with HTTPs without making any changes to the application?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, reverse-proxy

I have a spring boot application which works over http.I do not want to touch the application - so no keystore etc. I want to use reverse proxy - i.e. the request will land at some other machine over TLS and
will get redirected to my spring boot application over secure socket layer. How it could be done?
***Edit:*** When I try to login to that site, developer tool console tells me:
"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx-uat.xxxx.com:4200/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://151.253.73.106:9091/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."
Nginx reverse proxy is being used.

Comment: Which reverse proxy do you want to use? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  It had not occurred to me earlier that it could be vendor specific. I guess it is Nginx. Actually already such an arrangement was in place. Now it is broken & I have to bring it back to life. So when they are saying it was working earlier - what could go wrong in an nginx reverse proxy setup?

Comment: Nginx is not do hard to configure. Usually it just works. So you have nginx already installed?

Comment: On client's machine it  is installed. I do not have access to it. Should I ask them to share their redirection rules?

Comment: That's a good start

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have edited the question with extra information. Pl. see if that console log is any helpful.

Comment: Adn what is running on ? 151.253.73.106

Comment: @SimonMartinelli  An angular front end application and a non-secure spring boot backend application.

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta I'm facing the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to use cloudflare. Cloudflare is free for basic use. You can create a new site, point to your HTTP URL and configure SSL as flexible. So, now your service is behind https. Cloudflare will act as proxy. Request will go to cloudflare via https, then it will be routed to your http.

Comment: This will only work if the app is running in the internet

Comment: Yes. I thought your service is hosted over internet

Comment: There is nothing in the question that says so